# How are the weights in 'optimal reconciling' of hierarchical forecasts in hts package calculated?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

Prof. Hyndman in the [paper] (https://robjhyndman.com/papers/Foresight-hts-final.pdf) mentions that weights are obtained by using linear regression against a set of dummy variables. I have two questions here:

a. what exactly is meant by linear regression against dummy variables?

b. why is it better than obtaining these weights by performing linear regression on the past data?

Comment: See https://otexts.org/fpp2/reconciliation.html

Comment: Thank you very much Prof. Hyndman. I did not know about the existence fpp2. I learned a great deal from fpp1.